# CSS: Style an empty box for the QR camera

Tags: html, css, camera, qr-code

I'm designing for a website that has QR Code scan function, and interface required as below.

When the camera is turned on, it will be full screen, the camera is covered by a transparent black layer, but in the middle is an unshielded square to scan the QR code.

[image]
I have designed like this
HTML:

```
<div class="videobox">
            <div class="shape-qr"></div>
            <div class="videobox__inner">
                <video id="video" autoplay playsinline ></video>
            </div>
         </div>
```

CSS:

```
.videobox, #video{
        text-align: center;
        position: relative;
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
    }
    .videobox .shape-qr{
        background: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        right:0;
        bottom: 0;
    }
```

The result was like this, but I did not know how to center the camera in a square space

[image]

Sympathy for English is not good, expect people to help!

Thank you!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's an example using `clip-path`. I used [this website](https://bennettfeely.com/clippy/) to make the shape.

```css
img{
  width:500px;
}
.element{
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  width:500px;
  height:500px;
  background:rgba(255,0,0,0.8) ;
  
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0% 0%, 0% 100%, 25% 100%, 25% 25%, 75% 25%, 75% 75%, 25% 75%, 25% 100%, 100% 100%, 100% 0%);
  clip-path: polygon(0% 0%, 0% 100%, 25% 100%, 25% 25%, 75% 25%, 75% 75%, 25% 75%, 25% 100%, 100% 100%, 100% 0%);
  
}
```

```html
<img src="https://www.gallaslabel.com/assets/1/7/Wine_Bottle_-_QR_Code.jpg" />
<div class="element">
</div>
```

Another way to do it is to cover the area using 4 divs - top, bottom, left,right

That's exactly [what this Expose jQuery plugin does.](http://code.chingr.com/jquery-expose/example.html)

Edit: There's also [this one](https://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/jQuery-Plugin-To-Set-Spotlight-Focus-On-DOM-Elements-SpotLight-js/) that user `border-width:10000px;`. Seems hacky but works.

Comment: Thanks very much! But how do the box always be a square and the camera will show up depending on the device? Can not set the camera size. Hope the helping.

Comment: You can replace the `%` with `px`.